# Is there an intrinsic energy-momentum associated with constraining forces that don't do work?

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, surface-tension

As an example, consider a continuous charge distribution, within Maxwell's model of classical electrodynamics, that is brought from infinity onto a spherical surface at a radius $r$ from the origin. This is held in place by a 'massless' surface providing the necessary Poincare forces. Is it physically consistent to say that this constraining surface remains massless, despite providing constraining forces that aren't doing any work?